# Input Type Length Increasing When Start Typing on Mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a simple contact form on mobile for a website. Form is working fine on desktop but when i'm opening it on smartphone/mobile devices the length of field is increasing. please see the images

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roPTg.png) | [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyhMx.png) | [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts0ff.png)

1. first image showing the 1st look when we open the web page on mobile
2. second is when i try to add value
3. third when i'm done with value for first two fields

code i'm doing

```css
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 360px) and (max-device-width : 640px) and (orientation : portrait)
{
    .table tr td input[type="text"],
    .table tr td input[type="email"]
    {
     width: 250px;
    }
    
    .table tr td input[type="text"]:focus,
    .table tr td input[type="email"]:focus
    {
     border: 1px solid #f15b25;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 360px) and (max-device-width : 640px) and (orientation : landscape)
{
.left_bottom table tr td input[type="text"],
.left_bottom table tr td input[type="email"]
{
 width: 480px;
 margin-left:1.5%;
}

.left_bottom table tr td input[type="text"]:focus,
.left_bottom table tr td input[type="email"]:focus
{
 border: 1px solid #f15b25;
}
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="senderName" class="wdlp_form" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="senderEmail" class="wdlp_form" required /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: Try to add full html css and if you use any CDN

Comment: please have a look at left side quote form on this page http://www.ranglerz.com/website-developer-lahore-pakistan.php

Comment: are you working now on that site ??

Comment: yes, trying to resolve it

Comment: ok go ahead. one suggestion dnt change td width

Comment: done with that, but still getting the issue, latest files are uploaded you can see now on web page

Comment: sounds good . but the web page is not responsive ..

Comment: yup its not fully responsive, can you please try it on any smartphone, hope you'll see it correctly